# Reading an element from a json object stored in a column

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```
+-------+--------------------------------
|__key__|______value____________________| 
|  1    | {"name":"John", "age": 34}    |
|  2    | {"name":"Rose", "age": 50}    |
```

I want to retrieve all age values within this dataframe and store it later within an array.

```
val x = df_clean.withColumn("value", col("value.age"))
x.show(false)
```

But this throws and exception.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Can't extract value from value#89: need struct type but got string;

How to resolve my requirement

**EDIT**

```
 val schema = existingSparkSession.read.json(df_clean.select("value").as[String]).schema
    val my_json = df_clean.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("jsonValue"))
    my_json.printSchema()
    val df_final = my_json.withColumn("age", col("jsonValue.age"))
    df_final.show(false)
```

Currently no exceptions are thrown. Yet I can't see any output also

EDIT 2

```
println("---+++++--------")
df_clean.select("value").take(1)
println("---+++++--------")
```

output

```
---+++++--------
---+++++--------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have long json and want to create schema then you can use `from_json` with schema.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\": 34}"),
  (2, "{\"name\":\"Rose\", \"age\": 50}")
).toDF("key", "value")

val schema = spark.read.json(df.select("value").as[String]).schema

val resultDF = df.withColumn("value", from_json($"value", schema))

resultDF.show(false)
resultDF.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+
|key|value     |
+---+----------+
|1  |{34, John}|
|2  |{50, Rose}|
+---+----------+
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- key: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

If you directly need to access the nested fields then you can use `get_json_object`

```
df.withColumn("name", get_json_object($"value", "$.name"))
  .withColumn("age", get_json_object($"value", "$.age"))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: for get_json_object im getting an error "cannot resolve symbol get_json_object"

Comment: please use `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` and also can you share the output of `df_clean.show`

Comment: @tharindu please check I have used exactly same data you provided.